# Setting an animation for a toolbar from the beginning

Tags: ios, animation, uitoolbar, uidatepicker

I have a `textfield` which has a `UIDatePicker` instead of a keyboard. I also made a `toolbar` not connected with the `datePicker` but that just appears when the `textfield` is tapped. The problem is the animations. The `datePicker` slides up nicely, but the `toolbar` just appears before the animation of the `datePicker` is done. This makes the whole thing look horrible. How would I set the animation to match the `datePickers`? I have no experience with animations and none of the other posts did any good for me.

---

### EDIT

Based on Tareks answer I was able to set the animation to slide up by doing the following.

First, Setting the toolbar to bottom of screen

`pickerBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 44)];`

Seconds, Changing the location of the toolbar in the animation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^(void) {

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 224-46, 320, 44);

    [pickerBar setFrame:rect];
```

Comment: please show what you tried..

Comment: I have tried nothig so far. But i could show you the toolbar and the datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code below to show your toolBar:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^(void) {
    toolBar.alpha = 1;
}];
```

**EDIT**:

`toolBar.alpha` should be 0.

**For Sliding:**
It is gonna something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
     int newY = yVal; // you can play with this newY.
     CGRect frame = toolBar.frame;
     frame.origin.y = newY;
     toolBar.frame  = frame;
}];
```

Comment: Do I need to do something else with this? I cant just put this in the code right? Sorry have no clue when it comes to animations

Comment: Yes just put this in your function, it equals to toolBar.hidden = NO;

Comment: I put this right after this line of code `[self.view addSubview:pickerBar];` but nothing happened

Comment: first toolBar.alpha should be 0, then when you want to show the toolBar put the above code.

Comment: Thanks it worked! But could you tell me the animation for making it slide up from the bottom?

Comment: Nvm, I think I can figure this out on my own now with your code. I would just change the x and y instead of the alpha right?

Comment: No problem, thanks again, this has been bothering me for a while

Answer (score 3):

you can use the inputAccessoryView for that reason.

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init...
```

Comment: Strange, just assign your pickerBar to it.